# Getting Issue in Parsing String Using PHP

Tags: php, json

**Here is the response that I am receiving.**

```
{  
    "StartTime":"2016-01-15T03:22:33.109787-05:00",
    "EndTime":"2016-01-15T03:22:34.2504378-05:00",
    "queryController":{  
        "TotalRecords":8355,
        "PageNumber":1,
        "PageSize":8,
        "DataFilters":[  

        ],
        "PropertyListing":[  
            {  
                "EntityName":"Product",
                "PropertyName":"IXOneId"
            },
            {  
                "EntityName":null,
                "PropertyName":"UPC12"
            }
        ],
        "EntityName":"QueryController"
    },
    "Products":[  
        {  
            "EntityName":"Product",
            "IXOneId":"SNL1080",
            "UPC12":"037014000245"
        },
        {  
            "EntityName":"Product",
            "IXOneId":"SNL1090",
            "UPC12":"747599617003"
        },
        {  
            "EntityName":"Product",
            "IXOneId":"SNL1079",
            "UPC12":"024182001822"
        },
        {  
            "EntityName":"Product",
            "IXOneId":"SNL1102",
            "UPC12":"745158300519"
        },
        {  
            "EntityName":"Product",
            "IXOneId":"SNL1077",
            "UPC12":"024182001891"
        },
        {  
            "EntityName":"Product",
            "IXOneId":"SNL1148",
            "UPC12":"039978003645"
        },
        {  
            "EntityName":"Product",
            "IXOneId":"SNL1110",
            "UPC12":"070670005759"
        },
        {  
            "EntityName":"Product",
            "IXOneId":"SNL1083",
            "UPC12":"037014000290"
        }
    ],
    "ResponseMessages":null,
    "EntityName":"ProductSearchReturn"
}
```

I want to get the values of **IXOneId** & **UPC12** values of that for all the records and wants to display it on my page. How to get this with help of PHP ? Kinda stuck on that. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you show what have you tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: I am new to PHP so don't know exact way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following variable `$string` contains your sample json string.
Decode using `json` decode and iterate over the inner `Products` array.

```
$json = json_decode($string);

foreach($json->Products as $product){
    print $product->IXOneId . ' ' . $product->UPC12 . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will output

```
SNL1080 037014000245
SNL1090 747599617003
SNL1079 024182001822
SNL1102 745158300519
SNL1077 024182001891
SNL1148 039978003645
SNL1110 070670005759
SNL1083 037014000290
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a JSON structure. Convert it to array using `json_decode` and then loop over it with a `while` loop or `for` loop to extract the data the way you need it.

Comment: I have tried it to get but was not able to get success. @stephenthedev

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in variable , here in $arr, then use json_decode .
Then you can use foreach

```
 $arr=json_decode($arr);
 print_r($arr->Products);
```